# How do you restrict certain HTML elements to certain roles using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authorization

I'm looking for the standard practice in specifying that a certain HTML element, like a "Create user" button should only be displayed when the user is logged-in and belongs to the role "Administrator."

For example, using Spring MVC in Java, the Spring Security tag library has a control that does just that:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_PRESIDENT')">
    <input type="button" value="Launch nuclear weapons"/>
</sec:authorize>
```

Whatever appears between the tags will only display when the user belongs to the role specified.

Does ASP.NET MVC have such feature?

Answer (score 5):

For Razor view engine:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("ROLE_PRESIDENT")) {
    <input type="button" value="launch nuclear weapons" />
}
```

For Webforms view engine:

```
<% if (User.IsInRole("ROLE_PRESIDENT")) { %>
    <input type="button" value="launch nuclear weapons" />
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need element level security across your site,  I suggest you create [custom `HtmlHelpers`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) per element that all implement your security rules for rendering.

*Note: wrapping `if` statements with role checks all over your views will not be maintainable*

Comment: agreed, it seems to be the closest equivalent to the Spring MVC code in the question (not that I know Spring MVC) though

Comment: Do you mean the HtmlHelper should check whether the user is authorized to complete the action? It should then decide whether to render an HTML object or not, I assume?

Answer (score 0):

@If User.IsInRole("Administrator") Then 'whatever
end if

something like should work